# I am unable to generate the Code Coverage report for iOS despite successfully running the unit test cases

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unit-testing, code-coverage

I am unable to generate the Code Coverage report for iOS despite successfully running the unit test cases.

Failed to merge raw profiles in directory /Users/sharanabasappa/****/****-ios-swift/DerivedData/****/Build/ProfileData/00008030-00160DCA367B402E to destination /Users/sharanabasappa/****/****-ios-swift/DerivedData/****/Build/ProfileData/00008030-00160DCA367B402E/Coverage.profdata: Aggregation tool '/Applications/Xcode 15.0.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/llvm-profdata' failed with exit code 1: warning: /Users/sharanabasappa/****/****-ios-swift/DerivedData/****/Build/ProfileData/00008030-00160DCA367B402E/70F81891-01EC-435E-9E1F-F622ACB359F6-4200.profraw: invalid instrumentation profile data (file header is corrupt)
error: no profile can be merged